# how to use php variable in a external javascript file by ajax?

Tags: ajax

Basically, I want to use a php variavle in a external Js file by ajax. For instance:

in a example.php file

```
<?php 
$a="123"
//and then I want to call a show() function through a onclick event later
<xxxxxxxxxxxxx......  onclick="show()">;
?>
```

in another example2.js file there is a function

```
show()
{
  var b
  // I want to assign $a's value to this variable b here.=> b=a

  //but I only want to do this way by using ajax.

}
```

Is there anybody can tell me how to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to insert the ajax_object.responceText into a value in a  and then get it with javascript?